# Swift Vapor 3 build error

Tags: vapor

When i create a new vapor 3 project .
I got this error when building .

I tried it in the beta and non beta versions ..
I reinstalled vapor 
but still have that error.

```
        No .build folder, fetch may take a while...
        Fetching Dependencies [                 •       ]
        Error: backgroundExecute(code: 1, error: "warning: \'fetch\' command is deprecated; use \'resolve\' instead\nerror: failed to clone; Cloning into bare repository 
    \'/Users/Mercury/Desktop/vapor/n/.build/repositories/http.git-9159899851620770205\'...\nerror: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: 
error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version, errno 0\nfatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly\n", output: "Fetching https://github.com/vapor/validation.git\nFetching 
    https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-zlib-support.git\nFetching https://github.com/vapor/http.git\nFetching https://github.com/vapor/sqlite.git\nFetching 
https://github.com/vapor/console.git\nFetching 
    https://github.com/vapor/core.git\nFetching
 https://github.com/vapor/crypto.git\nFetching 
    https://github.com/vapor/database-kit.git\nFetching 
https://github.com/vapor/routing.git\nFetching https://github.com/vapor/websocket.git\nFetching 
https://github.com/vapor/service.git\nFetching 
    https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git\nFetching 
https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-ssl-support.git\nFetching https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git\nFetching 
https://github.com/vapor/template-kit.git\nFetching 
    https://github.com/vapor/url-encoded-form.git\nFetching \https://github.com/vapor/multipart.git\nFetching https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git\nFetching 
    https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-ssl.git\nFetching 
    https://github.com/vapor/sql.git\nFetching https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite.git\n")
```

Comment: Post your Package.swift file and also the result of `vapor --version`

Comment: All lasr versions

Comment: I meet the same issue, I guess swift 4.2 is not good support for Vapor 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the version is a good solution for this issue if you are using this old version ..